# How to place network and image picker image in a single grid or listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[For example on the given image 1 and 2 as a network image in the grid view and others are captured locally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOAub.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use gridview.count

```
GridView.count(
  children:[
     //widget1() to display NetworkImage
     //Widget2() for other NewtorkImage(),
     //widget3 to display image captured from imagepicker.
     //widget4
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can make a list of all images you have and then you can conditionally render the images on the screen. See below example:

```
List<String> imgUrls = [];
GridView.builder(ctx,index){
    gridDelegate:SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(  
                crossAxisCount: 10,  
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,  
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0  
            ),
  //check if the url is valid
  if(isValid) {
    NetworkImage(url:imgUrls[index]);
  }else if(isValidPath){
    //check if the user has uploaded photo to local and path is valid
    Image.asset(imgUrls[index]);
  }else{
    //show error widget
    SizedBox();
  }
}
```